# Returning custom HttpResponseMessage as IActionResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, httpresponse, actionresult, webapi

I have a web api which returns `IActionResult`.

I return `FileContentResult` from this api like this

```
return new FileContentResult(model.Content, ContentType)
{
    EnableRangeProcessing = true
};
```

I have a requirement in which I now want to control `StatusCode` myself, rather than `FileContentResult` decide itself.

I don't find any way to do this.

Basically I want to return my own designed `HttpResponseMessage` in which I can set headers and other stuff myself.

But I don't find any way to do this for `IActionResult` type.

The only thing that I thought could work is to use `ResponseMessageResult` something like this

```
var content = new ByteArrayContent(bytesWithValidationData);
var response = new HttpResponseMessage();
response.Content = content;
response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.PartialContent;
response.Content.Headers.ContentRange = new ContentRangeHeaderValue(from, to);

return new ResponseMessageResult(response);
```

But its response is not same as HttpResponse, it just returns json result with `HttpResponseMessage` object details but does not actually return Http response considering content type etc. where I can download the file.

It gives result like this

[image]

Is there any way I can return my designed file result type http response?

Comment: Is this classic web API, or ASP.NET Core?

Comment: @IanKemp - Asp.net Core. So this is the full name of the class `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult`

Answer (score 2):

Legacy ASP.NET Core web API had special handling for raw `HttpResponseMessage` instances. ASP.NET Core does not - your controller action **has to** return an instance of `IActionResult`.

In your case, I would suggest subclassing `FileContentResult` and manipulating the status code, then returning your subclass from your controller. Something like the following:

```
public class MyFileContentResult : FileContentResult
{
    public override Task ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
    {
        context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = <your status code>;

        var result = base.ExecuteResultAsync(context);

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Getting this error at the line where the status is getting set :( `System.InvalidOperationException: 'StatusCode cannot be set because the response has already started.'
`

Comment: It worked when I moved line `context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = <your status code>;` above line `var result = base.ExecuteResultAsync(context);` :) In short now the response is getting started after assigning the new status code

Comment: Please edit your answer and I will mark it as correct answer